# How to convert an array to a html table

Tags: php

Can someone help me with this array that I have? I want to create a table that is a maximum of 5 columns and a maximum of 15 rows. If there are only 4 rows, for example, then only 4 rows should be shown instead of the 15. If there are only 3 cells that have data then the the remaining 2 should be padded with `$nbsp;`.

Here is my sample array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => test1
            [item_id] => 1
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => test2
            [item_id] => 2
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => test3
            [item_id] => 3
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => test4
            [item_id] => 4
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [name] => test5
            [item_id] => 5
        )
    [5] => Array
        (
            [name] => test6
            [item_id] => 6
        )
)
```

---

My data repeats if there is a new row added. This is my issue at present.

```
$row = count( $array ) / 5;
$col = 5;

echo'<table border="1" width="700">';

for( $i = 0; $i < $row; $i++ )
{
    echo'<tr>';
    for( $j = 0; $j < $col; $j++ ) {
        if( ! empty( $array[$j] ) ) {
            echo '<td>'.$array[$j]['item_id'].'</td>';
        }
    }
    echo'</tr>';
}

echo'</table>';
```

Comment: What have you tried? And do you know the basic control structures of PHP (`if`/`else`/`elseif`, `for`/`foreach`, `while`, `do`-`while`, `break`, etc.)? http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.control-structures.php http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: N-level array into table has answered here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746079/how-to-create-a-html-table-from-a-php-array/47015800#47015800

Comment: This thread has been answered here [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746079/how-to-create-a-html-table-from-a-php-array/47068295#47068295)

Answer (score 11):

Let's call your array `$rows`, ok?

```
echo "<table>";
foreach ($rows as $row) {
   echo "<tr>";
   foreach ($row as $column) {
      echo "<td>$column</td>";
   }
   echo "</tr>";
}    
echo "</table>";
```

Using `foreach` is more idiomatic for looping trough arrays in php, and it greatly increase your code's readability. Plus, the only variable you need for this is one containing the array itself.

Comment: Thanks cbrandolino, I'll give this a try now. brb

Comment: cbrandolino, This does work but what I need is something that will allow me the flexibility to specify 5 columns. Any additional data in the array should be wrapped into a new row. Your code simply echos the data out exactly as it is in the loop.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you then. I would suggest to filter the array first and then go with this, but it's likely that you would find that code more complicated. Just use @Sarfraz code and change the for condition like this: `for ($i=$start; $i=$start+5, $i++)`, where $start is the first element you want to display.

Comment: Thanks for your help cbrandolino. If you compare my code with that of Sarfraz's, you'll see that the functionality is the same. I need to rethink this a bit but I really do appreciate your help. What is happening with my code is that I am getting repeating rows. The rows are cutting off at 5 columns which is exactly what I need but the first row is then repeated on the seconf row.

Comment: @jim, you're welcome. Anyway, there's really much to rethink: just assign $start a value and use this code http://pastebin.com/du220DTy - based on yours - instead of what you posted.

Answer (score 2):

Check out:

[PHP array to table](http://www.terrawebdesign.com/multidimensional.php)

[Or this class](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2047-PHP-Output-a-two-dimensional-array-in-an-HTML-table.html)

It is basically simple logic something like this:

```
echo "<table border=\"5\" cellpadding=\"10\">";

for ($i=0; $i < count($input); $i++)
{
    echo "<tr>";
    for ($c=0; $c<$cols; $c++)
    {
      echo "<td>$input[$i]</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Thanks Sarfraz, can you please have a look at what I've got above? I've edited my post.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a snippet I wrote to test converting a php array to html.

```
    $row = array(
        'column 1' => 'value',
        'column 2' => 'value',
        'column 3' => 'value',
        'column 4' => 'value',
        'column 5' => 'value',
        'column 6' => 'value',
        'column 7' => 'value',
    );

    $rows = array($row, $row, $row, $row, $row, $row, $row, $row, $row, $row);

    print array_to_html($rows);


function array_to_html($data) {
    $report = "";

    if (count($data) > 0) {

        $report .= "<table>";
        $report .= sprintf("<tr><th>%s</th></tr>", join("</th><th>", array_keys($data[0])));

        foreach ($data as $row) {

            $report .= "<tr>";

            foreach ($row as $column) {
                $report .= "<td>$column</td>";
            }
            $report .= "</tr>";
        }
        $report .= "</table>";
    } else {
        $report = "No data";
    }

    return $report;
}
```