# JSON values into HTML table

Tags: php, html, json

I have a *table.html*, *data.php* and *json.csv* within the same folder.

*data.php* is doing `fopen("json.csv","r")` to read from *json.csv*.

How can I display the JSON objects as a table within *table.html*?

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js">
function display(){
 $.post('data.php',function(data){
 $("#txtJSON").html(data); 
 });
  }

  </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="display()">
  <table id="#jobtable">
  <input type="text" id="txtJSON" />
  </table>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: That is not a table but a input field

Comment: This thread has been answered here [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746079/how-to-create-a-html-table-from-a-php-array/47068295#47068295)

Answer (score 9):

You just need `json_decode` and some iteration

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

I'll show you a very simplistic way to do the PHP.  You don't tell anything about the JSON, so I'm assuming its flat (not nested).  I think you might want to alter the client side stuff too.  Make `txtJSON` into an empty `div`, which will be filled with the output from the PHP.

```
$file = $fopen("json.csv", 'r');
$fileText = fread($file, filesize($file));
$arr = json_decode($fileText, true); //i prefer associative array in this context

echo "<table>";
foreach($arr as $k=>$v)
    echo "<tr><td>$k</td><td>$v</td></tr>";
echo "</table>";
```

If your JSON is not flat and simple, what would you like the resulting table to look like?

Answer (score 2):

Here I have taken json data in to $json variable, and then use foreach loop to create table from json data.

```
foreach ($data as $key => $jsons) {
 $table ='<table class="'.$jsons['class'].'" border="1">';
 foreach ($jsons as $rkey => $rvalue) {
    if($rkey=='head')
    {
        $table.='<tr>';
        foreach($rvalue as $rvv)
        {
            $table.='<th>'.$rvv.'</th>';
        }
        $table.='</tr>';
    }else
    if($rkey=='rows')
    {
        foreach($rvalue as $rvv)
        {
            $table.='<tr>';
            foreach($rvv as $rv)
            {
                $table.='<td>'.$rv.'</td>';
            }
            $table.='</tr>';
        }
    }
 }
}
echo $table;
?>
```

I have taken reference from  http://www.tutsway.com/create-table-from-json.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library for converting Json to Standard HTML table: [Json-To-Html-Table](https://github.com/afshinm/Json-to-HTML-Table)