# JSON ENCODE output in table

Tags: php, javascript, html

I want to print json_encode array into a table format inside html.I tried the following method:

```
<table align="center">
   <tr>
        <td style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto;margin-top:50px">
            <div id="container2" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto;margin-top:50px"></div>       
        </td>
        <td><?php echo json_encode($names1,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

but sadly its just giving the output in normal json_encode. How to print the json_encode output as a table?

Comment: Walk through each member using `foreach` and output it with proper `<tr>` and `<td>` tags.

Comment: see you cant use foreach loop with json_encode na?

Comment: Oh, it's ENcode. Why do you want to use `json_encode()` in the first place? What is your desired output?

Comment: just to output the value got from mysql, to html near the graph

Comment: Why do you need `json_encode()` for that? Why not just output a normal table?

Comment: itried its giving array to string conversion error.                     check the code i have added parts of the code.

Comment: <?php foreach( $names1 as $n){
                       echo "<tr><td>";
                       echo $n;
        echo "</td></tr>";}
        ?></table>

Comment: while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query1)){
 $names1[$indexb]=array($row['username'],$row['score']);
 $indexb++;
}

Comment: sorry i am not finding how to add code to the question.

Comment: You should have an "edit" button. Anyway, using `json_encode()` is definitely the wrong way to go about this. I can't tell from your code above where the problem is, but outputting HTML is the way to go - it'll be worth trying to fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not clear to me, but it sounds like you just want to display an array in HTML table format so I'm not sure what json_encode has to do with it.

However, this has been answered before:

[How to create a HTML Table from a PHP array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746079/how-to-create-a-html-table-from-a-php-array)

Comment: no i want to output the json_encode value into tables. simply echoing it will give the output in the following way [["Ahmed",6],["Aldein",3],["Allouh",2],["Salim",0]]

Comment: itried foreach but its giving me array to string conversion error

Comment: dued ur awesome..it was already given na ididn notice sorry... :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want each value in it's own td element, then you will need to iterate over the array and output the td elements yourself. You can do this in php from the $names array, or in JavaScript on the client using a json array. I'd do it in php.

To output each pair in  its own row

```
foreach ($names1 as &$value) {
Echo "<tr>"
Echo "<td>"
Echo  $value[0]
Echo "</td>
Echo "<td>"
Echo  $value[1]
Echo "</td>
Echo "<tr>
}
```

Comment: ididn understand it properly..how ? imean how to get the json_encode element individually?

Comment: but its a two dimensional array. Its giving array to sting conversion error

Comment: see these are the values in the array...how to print them? [["Ahmed",6],["Aldein",3],["Allouh",2],["Salim",0]]