# How can I parse JSON into a html table using PHP?

Tags: php, html, json, html-table

I have to get a table in my website. And have to get the data for this table from
"http://west.basketball.nl/db/json/stand.pl?szn_Naam=2014-2015&cmp_ID=373"
I've tried a lot of thing but nothing works....

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
   <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" 
       src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
    <?php
    $json=file_get_contents("http://west.basketball.nl/db/json
    /stand.pl?szn_Naam=2014-2015&cmp_ID=373");
            $data =  json_decode($json);

        if (count($data)) {
            // Open the table
            echo "<table>";

            // Cycle through the array
            foreach ($data as $stand) {

                // Output a row
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>$afko</td>";
                echo "<td>$positie</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }

            // Close the table
            echo "</table>";
        }
    ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry fellows... forgot to say but this is written in a .php file

Comment: What does not work? Have you set `error_reporting` to `E_ALL` and `display_errors` to `on` in your dev environement?

Comment: what do you mean?.... i guess not.... still new to php

Comment: I guess the problem is that url_fopen is set to disabled due to security reason. Add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to the beginnig of your PHP script. And make sure in your .htaccess or php.ini that `display_errors` is set to `On` or have a view into the PHP log file after your request.

Comment: i dont know what a php.ini is and dont know what a .htaccess is so.....   , i did add the error reporting but it still doesnt work.
There is one error in the console, its about the drawing set of the html and how its not declared and about US-ASCCI or something?

Comment: You don't see PHP errors on the client side error console because PHP is a server side thing. You have to look into the PHP error log on your webserver to figure that out. Or you create a `.htaccess` file in the folder where your script is and put the following line into it: `display_errors On`.

Comment: This thread has been answered here [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746079/how-to-create-a-html-table-from-a-php-array/47068295#47068295)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Ok first thing to do when getting data from an external source is to understand what is being returned.

So do

```
<?php
$json=file_get_contents("http://west.basketball.nl/db/json/stand.pl?szn_Naam=2014-2015&cmp_ID=373");
$data =  json_decode($json);

print_r($data);
```

Result:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [stand] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [afko] => Risne Stars HS 1
                    [ID] => 2091
                    [status] => Actief
                    [gespeeld] => 3
                    [percentage] => 100.0
                    [punten] => 6
                    [tegenscore] => 149
                    [eigenscore] => 191
                    [datum] => 2014-10-05
                    [saldo] => 42
                    [team] => Risne Stars Heren 1
                    [positie] => 1
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [afko] => D.B.V. Arriba HS 2
                    [ID] => 1813
                    [status] => Actief
                    [gespeeld] => 2
                    [percentage] => 0.0
                    [punten] => 0
                    [tegenscore] => 116
                    [eigenscore] => 102
                    [datum] => 2014-10-05
                    [saldo] => -14
                    [team] => D.B.V. Arriba Heren 2
                    [positie] => 10
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [afko] => The Valley Bucketeers HS 2
                    [ID] => 2430
                    [status] => Actief
                    [gespeeld] => 2
                    [percentage] => 0.0
                    [punten] => 0
                    [tegenscore] => 177
                    [eigenscore] => 70
                    [datum] => 2014-10-05
                    [saldo] => -107
                    [team] => The Valley Bucketeers Heren 2
                    [positie] => 11
                )

            [3] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [afko] => Uitsmijters HS 2
                    [ID] => 2143
                    [status] => Actief
                    [gespeeld] => 2
                    [percentage] => 100.0
                    [punten] => 4
                    [tegenscore] => 79
                    [eigenscore] => 161
                    [datum] => 2014-10-05
                    [saldo] => 82
                    [team] => Uitsmijters Heren 2
                    [positie] => 2
                )

            [4] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [afko] => Picker Reds HS 1
                    [ID] => 2056
                    [status] => Actief
                    [gespeeld] => 3
                    [percentage] => 66.7
                    [punten] => 4
                    [tegenscore] => 193
                    [eigenscore] => 184
                    [datum] => 2014-10-05
                    [saldo] => -9
                    [team] => Picker Reds Heren 1
                    [positie] => 3
                )

            [5] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [afko] => Peatminers HS 2
                    [ID] => 6247
                    [status] => Actief
                    [gespeeld] => 1
                    [percentage] => 100.0
                    [punten] => 2
                    [tegenscore] => 36
                    [eigenscore] => 64
                    [datum] => 2014-10-05
                    [saldo] => 28
                    [team] => Peatminers Heren 2
                    [positie] => 4
                )

            [6] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [afko] => Jolly Jumpers HS 1
                    [ID] => 1994
                    [status] => Actief
                    [gespeeld] => 2
                    [percentage] => 50.0
                    [punten] => 2
                    [tegenscore] => 103
                    [eigenscore] => 119
                    [datum] => 2014-10-05
                    [saldo] => 16
                    [team] => Jolly Jumpers Heren 1
                    [positie] => 5
                )

            [7] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [afko] => TONEGO '65 HS 2
                    [ID] => 2120
                    [status] => Actief
                    [gespeeld] => 2
                    [percentage] => 50.0
                    [punten] => 2
                    [tegenscore] => 107
                    [eigenscore] => 122
                    [datum] => 2014-10-05
                    [saldo] => 15
                    [team] => TONEGO '65 Heren 2
                    [positie] => 6
                )

            [8] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [afko] => Amical HS 2
                    [ID] => 1791
                    [status] => Actief
                    [gespeeld] => 3
                    [percentage] => 33.3
                    [punten] => 2
                    [tegenscore] => 180
                    [eigenscore] => 195
                    [datum] => 2014-10-05
                    [saldo] => 15
                    [team] => Amical Heren 2
                    [positie] => 7
                )

            [9] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [afko] => S.V.Z.W. HS 2
                    [ID] => 5526
                    [status] => Actief
                    [gespeeld] => 3
                    [percentage] => 33.3
                    [punten] => 2
                    [tegenscore] => 174
                    [eigenscore] => 151
                    [datum] => 2014-10-05
                    [saldo] => -23
                    [team] => S.V.Z.W. Heren 2
                    [positie] => 8
                )

            [10] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [afko] => Twente Buzzards HS 3
                    [ID] => 2294
                    [status] => Actief
                    [gespeeld] => 3
                    [percentage] => 33.3
                    [punten] => 2
                    [tegenscore] => 196
                    [eigenscore] => 151
                    [datum] => 2014-10-05
                    [saldo] => -45
                    [team] => Twente Buzzards Heren 3
                    [positie] => 9
                )

        )

    [nummer] => OHS2C
    [version] => 1.0
    [aantal_teams] => 11
    [id] => 373
    [seizoen] => 2014-2015
    [naam] => Oost Afdeling Heren Senioren 2e klasse C
    [gewijzigd] => 2014-10-05 18:34:25
)
```

So now you know you are dealing with an OBJECT and not scalar values or an array.

So try this code:-

```
<?php
    $json=file_get_contents("http://west.basketball.nl/db/json/stand.pl?szn_Naam=2014-2015&cmp_ID=373");
    $data =  json_decode($json);

    if (count($data->stand)) {
        // Open the table
        echo "<table>";

        // Cycle through the array
        foreach ($data->stand as $idx => $stand) {

            // Output a row
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>$stand->afko</td>";
            echo "<td>$stand->positie</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }

        // Close the table
        echo "</table>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Wow Thank a lot it finally works :D Do you know a way to make it sort bij the positions? 1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.9.10.11 and so on so on

Answer (score 26):

If you want recursive way:

```
public static function jsonToDebug($jsonText = '')
{
    $arr = json_decode($jsonText, true);
    $html = "";
    if ($arr && is_array($arr)) {
        $html .= self::_arrayToHtmlTableRecursive($arr);
    }
    return $html;
}

private static function _arrayToHtmlTableRecursive($arr) {
    $str = "<table><tbody>";
    foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {
        $str .= "<tr>";
        $str .= "<td>$key</td>";
        $str .= "<td>";
        if (is_array($val)) {
            if (!empty($val)) {
                $str .= self::_arrayToHtmlTableRecursive($val);
            }
        } else {
            $str .= "<strong>$val</strong>";
        }
        $str .= "</td></tr>";
    }
    $str .= "</tbody></table>";

    return $str;
}
```

Then call `echo YourClass::jsonToDebug($jsonText)`;

My test on [http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0d718d0876ff24d141f451449a961081f0a48598)

Comment: Best answer,  since it's 1) structure-agnostic and 2) code-efficient (recursive)

Comment: Great! You could also change `$str .= "<strong>$val</strong>";` to `$str .= '<strong>' . var_export($val, true) . '</strong>';` to display falsey values, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Why not try :

```
$data = json_decode($json, true);
```

Comment: Explanation: the second argument (true) tells json_decode() to return an associative array rather than object of the given data which can be more intuitive to work with if you're not into OO programming.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, the issue is with the variables you are using - `$afko` and `$positie`. Please try with the below code -

```
// Cycle through the array
foreach ($data as $stand) {
    // Output a row
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td> . $stand['afko'] . </td>";
    echo "<td> . $stand['positie'] . </td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code below can be useful for dynamically converting your entire table without having to define column names.

```
 echo "<table>";
        echo "<tr>";
        foreach(array_keys($your_array[0]) as $head){
            echo "<td>$head</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>";

        foreach($your_array as $row){
            echo "<tr>";            
            foreach($row as $col){
                echo "<td>$col</td>";
            }
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";

        return $posicoes;
```

Answer (score 0):

Old post, but a simpler solution:

```
echo '<pre>'. print_r(  json_decode($json), true)).'</pre>';
```

- php json_decode: unserialize json string
- php print_r: print object content, using CRLF
- html <pre>: show text as HTML

You get your json in HTML on your browser like:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [field_1] => 1
    [field_2] => teste
    [other] => aaaa
    [another] => bbbb
)
```