# How can i parse json to a html table using PHP?

Tags: php, html, json, html-table

I have json file like this

```
[{
    "Shop_name": "916",
    "Shop_id": "916TCR",
    "Address":"cdsasffafa"
    "numbers": "4",
    "mob_no": "9447722856"
}, {
    "Shop_name": "Chicking",
    "Shop_id": "CKGTCR",
    "Address":"afagagg",
    "numbers": "8",
    "mob_no": "6767564532"
}]
```

i want to see this as HTML Table with row head as Shop_name,Shop_id,Address
and Data in next row.

i tried decoding it and display as table ([How can i parse json into a html table using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26213049/how-can-i-parse-json-into-a-html-table-using-php)).
but Json File format is diffrent here.
Also like to know if Json File gets bigger with [0],[1],[2]....

Comment: I dont think that is valid JSON with those odd double quotes

Comment: Corrected  JSON !@RiggsFolly

Comment: So now the caracter set is fixed, it just a case of doing some coding

Comment: Please show the code actual that you have actually used to try to get it to work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should parse your json data to php object than you should iterate your data like below;

```
$myData = <<<JSON

[
{"Shop_name":"minh",
  "Shop_id":"916TCR",
  "Address":"cdsasffafa",
  "numbers":"4",
  "mob_no":"9447722856"
},
{"Shop_name":"Chig",
 "Shop_id":"CKGTCR",
 "Address":"afagagg",
 "numbers":"8",
 "mob_no":"6767564532"
}
]

JSON;

$myObject = json_decode($myData);

?>
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Shop Name</td>
    <td>Shop ID</td>
    <td>Address</td>
    <td>Numbers</td>
    <td>Mob No</td>
</tr>
<?PHP
foreach($myObject as $key=>$item)
{
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?PHP echo $item->Shop_name; ?></td>
        <td><?PHP echo $item->Shop_id; ?></td>
        <td><?PHP echo $item->Address; ?></td>
        <td><?PHP echo $item->numbers; ?></td>
        <td><?PHP echo $item->mob_no; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?PHP
}
?>
</table>
```

A working example is here: http://ideone.com/IqZLMs

PS: You should fix this ” quote to "