# Print each element of json curl execution

Tags: php, json, curl

I have a curl function to call a service that return output like this

```
[{"idpacket":1,"packetname":"Silver","packetdesc":"Silver is da best","packetprize":"Rp 20000","packettime":"365 days"}]
```

I wanna echo all of element into table row

How i do that? I always get error on foreach function. Please help

This is my code:

```
<?php
//step1
$cSession = curl_init(); 
//step2
curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_URL,"http://localhost:8080/packet");
curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
//step3
$result=curl_exec($cSession);
//step4
curl_close($cSession);
//
foreach ((array) $result as $item) {
print_r($item['idpacket']);
 }
?>
```

Thank you :)

Comment: So what is the issue with the above given code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i parse json into a html table using PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26213049/how-can-i-parse-json-into-a-html-table-using-php)

Comment: You want field names in columns or rows ?

Comment: Incomplete issue --> you are talking about errors: Include them into your post to get more help !

Comment: the foreach function doesn't result anything, just blank @MayankPandeyz

Comment: no i think,, the solution doesnt work on my case @RakeshSoni

Comment: i wanna field name in column @Code3d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this conclusion as I understood

write this code and check :

```
print_r((array)$result);
```

its place your JSON into an array does not decode your JSON like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => [{"idpacket":1,"packetname":"Silver","packetdesc":"Silver is da best","packetprize":"Rp 20000","packettime":"365 days"}]
)
```

if you want to access 'idpacket'

write like this:

```
$result_array = json_decode($result,true);

foreach ((array) $result_array as $item) {
      print_r($item['idpacket']);
}
```

Comment: thanks it's work like what i want. if i may know,, the curl result json, is that a json or what ? how come we must decode again in variable result array. i dont understand. but thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

You could write something like

```
<?php
$resultArr = json_decode($result,true);

$header="<tr>";
$row="<tr>";
echo "<table>";

foreach($resultArr[0] as $col => $val)
{
  $header.="<td>".$col."</td>";
  $row.="<td>".$val."</td>";
}

$header.="</tr>";
$row.="</tr>";

echo $header;
echo $row;
echo "</table>";

?>
```