# Creating viewable results of API data

Tags: php, html, arrays, json

I know this may be relatively often asked question but all other questions that I've seen are much more advanced. I'm still trying to learn and need the dumbed down version of help LOL

Just trying to get JSON data returned from calling an API into a readable html format for a webpage on Wordpress.

Other than the API call itself and the html details, this is what I had for just getting the data sorted, but yet it's not working.  Can anyone provide the very basic ABC answer on how to get this working?  What am I missing? Once I have the first one down, or understand what's wrong I'll be able to proceed with others on my own.  Thanks!

```
$jsonObj = json_decode($response);

//Show latest items first
$latestitems = array_reverse($jsonObj->results);

//Loop through results
foreach($latestitems as $showObj)
    //Organize results into table
    $pageCSS = "<style>
           .recipe-wrapper{
            display:grid;
            grid-template-columns: 150px 150px 150px;
             }
            </style>";
```

Code listed above.

Comment: The simplest way is to create a `<table>` with a row for each element of the array.

Comment: There are many tutorials on how to create HTML tables in PHP.

Comment: The CSS shouldn't be inside the loop.

Comment: All this does is loop and keep declaring a string with some css in it. It doesn't _do_ anything, and it doesn't even try to output the actual data at all either which is why it doesn't work (and it's a bit unclear how you expected it to)

Comment: As mentioned, I'm still learning and trying to use other real life examples and apply them to my needs.  This is the example that I have been trying to use as a guide to better understand how they used it and apply it to my own needs.  
https://rapidapi.com/blog/integrate-external-api-wordpress/

I can call the API data by itself, but as soon as I start to create the array and sort/ loop the results, I run into issues.

Comment: If you are still learning, my recommendation would be to break this down into smaller steps. First, skip the API and JSON for now. I know that's the more exciting stuff, but get the basics down. Start with just a boring array, loop over it. https://3v4l.org/XLMYg

Comment: Thanks all...I'll look elsewhere or try to hire someone I guess.  I understand the API/ JSON part, just cant figure out how to get the results out of the JSON data and not seeing any clear cut tutorials online for doing so, or else Im not looking in the right places.  I can understand the basics of PHP and know HTML, CSS, etc. but needed help putting it all together and understanding why this example isn't working for me.   I found one Wordpress plugin but they want $200-300 and Im not sure it would even fulfill my needs.  Frustrated.

Comment: You've started the right way with your loop, assuming the decoded json is an array. Now how about trying to `echo` some of the data from the items within it, like Chris's demo shows? Generally one of the first things you learn when studying the basics is how to make your program display data, usually by using `echo`. So even if you're stuck on the specifics of the html table formatting, you ought to have perhaps grasped that bit at least - unless you're not studying php in a sensible sequence but instead trying to hack together things from random, overcomplicated tutorials?

Comment: Have a look at a much simpler example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26213455/5947043

Comment: Look into `var_dump` so that you can visualize the data. Consider wrapping it in a `<pre>` tag, too. Once you make the API call, you'll probably have any array. Once you have an array, you can loop