# Create HTML table from PHP Multidimensional array

Tags: php, html, arrays

I have a multidimensional array that is being built pulled from a file structure.

I am trying to use this array to create dynamic HTML tables based on the key for each item.
The script I am using to pull the file structure is making each folder into the keys of the array.

So the array is outputting like this:

```
Array(
[english] => Array
    (
        [term1] => Array
            (
                [circ] => Array
                    (
                        [Unit1] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => file.zip
                            )

                        [Unit2] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => file.zip
                            )

                        [Unit3] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => file.zip
                            )

                        [Unit4] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => file.zip
                            )

                    )

                [type] => Array
                    (
                        [Unit1] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => file.zip
                            )

                        [Unit2] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => file.zip
                            )

                        [Unit3] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => file.zip
                           )

                        [Unit4] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => file.zip
                            )

                    )

            )

        [term2] => Array
            (
                [circ] => Array
                    (
                        [Unit1] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => file.zip
                            )

                        [Unit2] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => file.zip
                            )

                        [Unit3] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => file.zip
                            )

                        [Unit4] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => file.zip
                            )

                    )

                [type] => Array
                    (
                        [Unit1] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => file.zip
                            )

                        [Unit2] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => file.zip
                            )

                        [Unit3] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => file.zip
                            )

                        [Unit4] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => file.zip
                            )

                    )

            )
        )
    )
```

What I am trying to output is a page with a table that will use the keys something like this.

title = engligh
heading 1 = term1
heading 2 = circ
content 1 = 
content 2 = Unit1
content 2 = Unit2
link = file.zip

```
{title}
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <th>{heading1}</th>
        <th>{heading2}</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>{content1}</td>
            <td><a href="{link}">{content2}</a></td>
        </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

I have not used PHP in over 5 years and to be honest was never very good at it in the first place, I have simply been thrown in the deep end at work and need some help to make this happen so any help given is very much appreciated!

**Edit**

So I have created a function that is pulling the first 2 level of keys from the array, however when I added in a third level it is just repeating the second level.
I think recursive is more along the lines of what I need however I can not get my head around that.

```
function recursive(array $array){
    foreach($array as $key => $value){
        echo $key, '<br>';
        //If $value is an array.
        if(is_array($value)){
            //We need to loop through it.
            foreach($value as $key1 => $value1) {
                echo ' - ' . $key1, '<br>';
                //if $value is an array.
                if(is_array($value1)){
                    foreach ($value1 as $key2 => $value2) {
                        echo '   - ' . $key2, '<br>';
                    }
                }else{
                    echo ' - ' . $key1, '<br>';
                }
            }
        } else{
            //It is not an array, so print it out.
            echo $key, '<br>';
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong with getting so many levels out of this function?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a HTML Table from a PHP array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746079/how-to-create-a-html-table-from-a-php-array)

Comment: Use a `foreach($your_array as $key => $value)` and use a combination of the key and values to get the data you want.

Comment: I understand that a foreach will need to be used, however I am getting stuck on what the combination of the key and values should be to be able to pull the data I need.

Comment: just dump your keys and values to see what you have.  go deeper if needed.  `var_dump($value);`

Comment: also... you never echo $value or $value1 if it isn't an array... just fyi.  not sure if that leads to any confusion.

Comment: Thanks gloomy.penguin I got it mostly working, good point on the the $value, that might solve my next problem!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you wanted it printed.  The example result is a little confusing.  This should show you how to work through the array, though.  I will see if I can get it a little closer to what you have up in the post but I don't get where the lowest level info is supposed to go exactly...

```
print "<style>table, td, tr {border: 1px solid black;}</style>"; 
print "<table>";

foreach($array as $class => $c_arr) {

   foreach($c_arr as $term => $t_arr) {

      foreach($t_arr as $circ_term => $ct_arr) {
         print "<tr><td>$class</td>";
         print "<td>$term</td>";
         print "<td>$circ_term</td>"; 

         foreach($ct_arr as $unit => $u_val) {
            print "<td>$unit = {$u_val[0]}</td>"; 
         }
         print "</tr>";
      }
   }
}
print "</table>";
```

---

yeah... based on your example of what you want... i still have no idea what it means.

```
title = engligh
heading 1 = term1
heading 2 = circ
content 1 = 
content 2 = Unit1
content 2 = Unit2
link = file.zip
```

so... what happens to type?  and there are 4 file.zip's listed each time.  and why is content 1 blank?  no clue.  you can also try this, though:

```
foreach($array as $class => $c_arr) {
   foreach($c_arr as $term => $t_arr) {
      print "title = $class<br/>";
      print "heading 1 = $term<br/>";
      foreach($t_arr as $circ_term => $ct_arr) {
         print "heading 2 = $circ_term<br/>"; 
         foreach($ct_arr as $unit => $u_val) {
            print "$unit = {$u_val[0]}<br/>"; 
         } 
      }
      print "<br/><br/>";
   }
   print "<br/><br/>";
} 

/*

title = english
heading 1 = term1
heading 2 = circ
Unit1 = file.zip
Unit2 = file.zip
Unit3 = file.zip
Unit4 = file.zip
heading 2 = type
Unit1 = file.zip
Unit2 = file.zip
Unit3 = file.zip
Unit4 = file.zip


title = english
heading 1 = term2
heading 2 = circ
Unit1 = file.zip
Unit2 = file.zip
Unit3 = file.zip
Unit4 = file.zip
heading 2 = type
Unit1 = file.zip
Unit2 = file.zip
Unit3 = file.zip
Unit4 = file.zip

*/
```

Comment: Thank you and sorry, I have realised that what I asked for wasn't going to work in the overall scheme of what I was trying to do, I will have to go back to the drawing board and rethink what I need.