# Conversion of php array into HTML table

Tags: php, html, arrays

I have PHP like this

```
$associativeArray = array("item1"=>"dogs", "item2"=>"cats",
                          "item3"=>"rats", "item4"=>"bats");
```

I want to show this data as a HTML table in this same page.

Comment: Well you might want to include: 1. Your attempt 2. Your current output 3. Your expected output (Please also read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: N-level array into table has answered here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746079/how-to-create-a-html-table-from-a-php-array/47015800#47015800

Comment: N-level array into table has answered here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746079/how-to-create-a-html-table-from-a-php-array/47015800#47015800

Comment: This thread has been answered here [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746079/how-to-create-a-html-table-from-a-php-array/47068295#47068295)

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through your array:

```
<table>
 <tbody>
   <?php 
     foreach($associativeArray as $key => $index) {
        ?> 
        <tr>
          <td><?php echo $key; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $index; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
     }
   ?>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: How can you answer the question if you don't even know the desired output from OP? Maybe he wants it all in one row?

Comment: `I'm not entirely sure on how to get this array into a HTML table` This is his array in a HTML table.

Comment: @Daan `<table><tr><td><?=implode($array);?></td></tr></table>` this is too

Comment: @Daan so is `<table><tr><td><?php var_dump($associativeArray); ?></td></tr></table>`

Comment: @Daan ^^ This is what I mean, you don't know how OP wants it. But I don't want to discuss here so I will leave it. Just one last thing to think about: Do you think when answering such question where no effort is shown that OP will put more, less or equal amount of effort into his next question? (<- Don't have to answer it just read it or think about it)

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code:

```
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php 
    foreach ($associativeArray as $key => $value) 
    {
        echo'<tr>'; 
        echo'<td>'. $key .'</td>';
        echo'<td>'. $value .'</td>';
        echo'<tr>';
    }
?>
</tbody>
```

Comment: How is this different from the other posted answer?

Answer (score 0):

In order to loop an [associate array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) it you need something like:

```
foreach ($array_expression as $key => $value) {
 echo $key;
 echo $value;
}
```

You should construct your `table`, before, during and after the loop, i.e.:

## Before:

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
```

## During:

```
foreach ($array_expression as $key => $value) {
 echo "<td>$value</td>";
}
```

## After:

```
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Your final code may look like this:

```
<?php
echo "<table><tbody><tr>";
foreach ($array_expression as $key => $value) {
   echo "<td>$value</td>";
}
echo "</tr></tbody></table>";
```

Comment: You know what I [think](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29775778/array-of-strings-in-a-table-with-keys-and-values#comment47682473_29775861) right now, so I will leave it and just say good morning :). (But didn't you missed a dollar sign in your foreach loop for: `array_expression` -> `$array_expression`?!)

Comment: @Rizier123 Good morning :). I surely do know what you think! but in this case the OP is "only starting out with php" So, I opened an exception. Your words add echo on me, I getting way better :)) Have a wonderful day.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use PHP environment to tabulate your array to avoid confusing:

```
    <?php
    $associativeArray = array("item1"=>"dogs", "item2"=>"cats", "item3"=>"rats", "item4"=>"bats");

    foreach($associativeArray as $index => $value){
        $rows .= "
            <tr>
                <td>$index</td>
                <td>$value</td>
            </tr>
        ";
    }

    print "
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>value</th>
            </tr>
            $rows
        </table>
        ";
    ?>
```

Comment: Why is it better this way?

Comment: reduces usage of <?php ?>  which is confusing and messy and to avoid "header already send" problem when spaces exist outside the PHP tag if not using properly