# Array multidimensional to html table

Tags: php, html, arrays, multidimensional-array

I know this question is repeated, but I cannot follow the examples for my situation. I'm querying Quake 2 servers for a personal project

```
 foreach ($results as $data) {
         echo "<pre>";
         print_r($data['players']);
    }
```

the info obtained:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [frags] => 7
        [ping] => 28
        [nick] => Player
        [gq_name] => Player
        [gq_score] => 7
        [gq_ping] => 28
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [frags] => 27
        [ping] => 31
        [nick] => lE'Heineken.
        [gq_name] => lE'Heineken.
        [gq_score] => 27
        [gq_ping] => 31
    )
```

)

So how can I move this info in a simple table?

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Players</th>
    <th>Frags</th>
    <th>Ping</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

I'm trying to do something like [q2servers](http://q2servers.com)

Thanks for your time, and sorry for my english. Regards

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a HTML Table from a PHP array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746079/how-to-create-a-html-table-from-a-php-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this then,

```
 <table>
    <tr>
        <th>Players</th>
        <th>Frags</th>
        <th>Ping</th>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach ($results as $data) {
     <?php foreach($data['players'] as $item){ ?>
        <tr>
           <td><?php echo $item['gq_name']; ?></td>
           <td><?php echo $item['gq_frags']; ?></td>
           <td><?php echo $item['ping']; ?></td>

        </tr>
   <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really what you need, but if I understood well, what you need is:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Players</th>
    <th>Frags</th>
    <th>Ping</th>
</tr>
<?php foreach ($results['players'] as $data) {
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $data['gq_name']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $data['gq_frags']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $data['ping']; ?></td>

</tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
```

Comment: I applied this example for the data server info (hostname, mapname, number of players) and works fine, but the player info is not displaying, cells of the table are empty, any thoughts?

Comment: try changing $results as $data, for $results['players'] as $data

Comment: <table>
    <tr>
        <th>Players</th>
        <th>Frags</th>
        <th>Ping</th>
    </tr>

    <?php foreach ($results['players'] as $data) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $data['gq_name']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $data['gq_frags']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $data['ping']; ?></td>

    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
    </table>

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\wamp\www\test\new.php on line 118

I dont know what is wrong there

Comment: what if you do $results['players'][0] as $data

Comment: "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\wamp\www\test\new.php on line 97" 

and the info from the print_r:

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [frags] => 0
            [ping] => 5
            [nick] => WallFly[BZZZ]
            [gq_name] => WallFly[BZZZ]
            [gq_score] => 0
            [gq_ping] => 5
        )

)

(there is one player online now)

Comment: ok you have to show what is in $results, that way I can see how is the array format

Comment: my index: require_once 'GameQ.php'; 

in gameq.php :  


        $results = array();
        foreach ($servers as $sid => $server) {
            $results[$sid] = array();
        }


        foreach ($packets as &$packet) {
            if (!isset($packet['response'])) $packet['response'] = null;
            $results[$packet['sid']][$packet['name']] = $packet['response'];
        }

        return $results;
    }

in my index: $results = $gq->requestData();

is this the info you need?

Comment: no, make a echo "<pre>"; print_r($results); echo "</pre>";

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this:

```
echo "
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Players</th>
    <th>Frags</th>
    <th>Ping</th>
</tr>";

foreach ($results as $data) {
    // print_r($data['players']);
    echo "
    <tr>
        <th>".$data['players']['nick']."</th>
        <th>".$data['players']['frags']."</th>
        <th>".$data['players']['ping']."</th>
    </tr>"
}

echo "</table>";
```

Comment: the cells are empty, cannot display the info, but "print_r" it does, I don't know what I'm missing