# How to create valid array from JSON to use it at foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, json, foreach

I have this text ($results):

```
{"data":{"summary":{"records":67,"page":1,"total":67,"hasMore":0},"reservations":[{"id":1111111,"property":"villadianna","from":"2016-07-18","to":"2016-07-25"},"pricing":{"price":1164.2400,"currency":"EUR","retail":1323},"clientInfo":{"firstName":"pera","lastName":"peric","email":"myemail@gmail.com"},"status":1,"offline":0},{"id":222222,"property":"villadianna", etc. ... ...
```

Now I need to get reserations array and make foreach loop so I try:

```
...
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$json = json_decode($result);
foreach ($json->reservations as $element) {
  print_r($element);
}
```

but I get errors:
[image]

How to create html table with foreach loop only for reservations ?

Comment: Do a `print_r($json);` and look at the object you are dealing with. `$json->data->reservations`

Comment: var_dump() is better, since it'll output booleans properly.

Comment: @MarcB Personally hate the output from `var_dump()` only use it if I really have to and `print_r()` does not show enough detail which is rare in my experince but you are probably right

Comment: ok I make print_r($json); and I get screen with json as a text

Comment: So that is what your `$json` object looks like read it and understand its structure. If you read the lables you will see `stdClass` (means an object) or `Array` (means an array)

Comment: this is begin of what I got: stdClass Object ( [summary] => stdClass Object ( [records] => 67 [page] => 1 [total] => 67 [hasMore] => 0 ) [reservations] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 11616946

Comment: if you want to pretty print json: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9120871/3392762

Answer (score 1):

```
...
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$json = json_decode($result);
foreach ($json->data->reservations as $element) {
  print_r($element);
}
```

Comment: but where is the table ? how to create html table with data ?

Comment: HTML 101. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746079/how-to-create-a-html-table-from-a-php-array