# PHP output array as an HTML table

Tags: php, arrays, html-table

I am trying to output an array as an html table, a sample of the array is..

```
Array
(
    [18] => Array
        (
            [colour] => red
            [size] => large
            [age] => 220
        )
        [19] => Array
        (
            [colour] => yellow
            [size] => small
            [age] => 20
        )
        [12] => Array
        (
            [colour] => brown
            [size] => large
            [age] => 2
        )
)
```

I am ok with doing a foreach for a simple array but does anyone have an example showing this being converted into a table for this type of array?

Comment: A table? Like any table? You don't have any requirements more specific than that? Here you go: `<table><tr><td>I'm a table!</td></tr></table>`. (Do at least make an effort to solve this problem, it helps clarify your intent and shows you're committed to solving it.)

Comment: Use multiple `foreach`s?

Comment: Good point, post updated!

Comment: @tadman you know your HTML quite well ;-) basic 101 stuff.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Experts Exchange Level A+++ Certified HTML Ph.D! (Fought the urge to add `<tbody>`)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a HTML Table from a PHP array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746079/how-to-create-a-html-table-from-a-php-array) - Googling `PHP array to table` yielded me about [3,450,000 results](https://www.google.ca/search?q=php+array+to+table)

Comment: `"I am ok with doing a foreach"` - Then have you tried?  `"being converted into a table for this type of array"` - And what 'type of array' is this?  Is there some reason a foreach wouldn't iterate over this array?  I guess it's not really clear to me where you're actually stuck here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$data = //your array
$html = "<table>";
foreach($data as $row) {
    $html .= "<tr>";
    foreach ($row as $cell) {
        $html .= "<td>" . $cell . "</td>";
    }
    $html .= "</tr>";
}
$html .= "</table>";
```

Your question is extremenly vague so this is a vague answer, but you should get the general idea :P

Comment: Concatenation: `+= !== .=`

Comment: Ah yeh my bad, changing now.