# How do I get custom PHP to use existing CSS styling in Wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am using woody snippets to insert php code to make an API call to return information in a table. How do I get the table to display using the default css from my wordpress theme?

I am new to PHP, but not to wordpress. And I know just enough CSS to get myself in trouble. So, I need ELI5 instructions.

My programmer provided the basic PHP code to call the API and return the data in a basic table. But, it looks horrid and there's no spacing or styling.

```
    $tableStart = "<table>";
    $tableEnd = "</table>";
    $trStart = "<tr>";
    $trEnd = "</tr>";
    $tdStart = "<td >";
    $tdEnd = "</td>";

    $fname = 'alabama_energy_data.json';

    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents($fname));

    echo $tableStart;

    foreach($data as $bill_data) 
    {
      echo $trStart;

      echo $tdStart . $bill_data->bill_id . $tdEnd . $tdStart . $bill_data->title . $tdEnd;


      echo $trEnd;
    }
    echo $tableEnd;
```

This returns a basic table with the data I need, but it's not styled. How do I get it to use the default CSS from our wordpress site that it's displaying in so that the table renders in a format that looks decent?

Comment: It's impossible to answer this question effectively without an understanding of the CSS classes that are provided as part of your currently-enabled Wordpress theme.

Comment: What esqew said. Your theme (or maybe a plugin?) may even apply some CSS classes to HTML tables (eg. `<table class="some-class-name yet-another-class-name" ...>`). If so, if you don't add those to your table then it'll use the default styling as provided by the browser.

Answer (score 0):

If your table isn't styled like it should be, then you're probably missing and `id` or `class` attribute at your table. You could check on what current attributes your "wordpress" tables have, and just add them to your table.

Example:

```
<table class="wp-class-table">
# OR
<table id="wp-id-table">
```

And one other thing, I personally don't really like the way you "echo" your data. If you want, you can read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4747673/9128538). It shows a nicer way to do it in my opinion.