# i need to get the table stage wise count with user in single line should be dynamic

Tags: php

> ```
>  Actual i get
>
> Array (
>     [person1] => Array
>         (
>             [stage1] => 4
>             [stage2] => 4
>             [stage3] => 4
>             [stage4] => 4
>             [stage5] => 2
>         )
>
>     [person2] => Array
>         (
>             [stage3] => 1
>         )
>
>     [person3] => Array
>         (
>             [stage1] => 2
>             [stage2] => 1
>             [stage4] => 1
>             [stage5] => 2
>         )
>
> )
> ```

1)Here They are 5 stages
stage1,stage2...stage5

2)they are 3 users
person1
person2
person3

some person dont have stages please keep as zero or empty in that stage

Covert this array into table as  below shown  image please help me

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccJLg.png

Comment: It doesn't clear what you have and what you trying to achieve. Please make proper code formatting and give clear example what you have and then what should be achieved.

Comment: possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746079/how-to-create-a-html-table-from-a-php-array/47068295#47068295) - please read [ask]

Comment: get the max columns of a single item, then loop over it use the key to match the others if its not set, set to 0, (or you know the stages already simply loop over them) trivial.. seems like homework, SO is not for that please show what you have tried.

Comment: <table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
 <tr>
 <th>User</th>
 <?php 
 foreach($allstages as $row){
  echo '<th>'.$row['stage'].'</th>';//here we get table header user,stage1,stage2...stageN as shown in image
 }?>
 </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  foreach($originalArray as $key=>$t){
  <tr>
        <td><?php echo $key; ?></td>//person1,person2,person3
  foreach( $t as $skey=>$p){
  //stages should be bind here 
   echo $skey;
   echo $p;
   echo '<td></td>';
  }
  </tr>
 }
</tbody>
</table>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to find all stages if this is not known up front and can be dynamic.
If you have that you can just build the table by iterating your data.

```
<?php

$data = [
  'person1' => [
    'stage1' => 4,
    'stage2' => 4,
    'stage3' => 4,
    'stage4' => 4,
    'stage5' => 2,
  ],
  'person2' => [
    'stage3' => 1,
  ],
  'person3' => [
    'stage1' => 2,
    'stage2' => 1,
    'stage4' => 1,
    'stage5' => 2,
  ],
];

$stages = [];
foreach ($data as $person) {
  foreach ($person as $stage => $number) {
    if (!in_array($stage, $stages)) {
      $stages[] = $stage;
    }
  }
}

var_dump($stages);

?>
<table>
  <th>person</th>
  <?php foreach ($stages as $stage): ?>
    <th><?php echo $stage; ?></th>
  <?php endforeach ?>
  <?php foreach ($data as $personName => $person): ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $personName; ?></td>
      <?php foreach ($stages as $stage): ?>
        <td><?php echo $person[$stage] ?? 0; ?></td>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tr>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

And the result:

```
array(5) { [0]=> string(6) "stage1" [1]=> string(6) "stage2" [2]=> string(6) "stage3" [3]=> string(6) "stage4" [4]=> string(6) "stage5" }

person  stage1  stage2  stage3  stage4  stage5
person1      4       4       4       4       2
person2      0       0       1       0       0
person3      2       1       0       1       2
```